Which software to model Fermi level position of graphene in an external electric field?
I want to model a graphene layer that is sandwiched in a pn junction under bias (the current flows orthogonal to the graphene layer). According to what I've found in literature graphene can be treated as a transparent tunneling barrier for a vertical current. So I wanted to seperate the simulations in two. I've already modelled the pn junction on its own with Ansys Lumerical CHARGE. From this I can extract the electric field strength at the position of the graphene layer as a function of the applied voltage.
Now for the 2nd part I am not sure how to go about this (DFT/Quantum espresso maybe?). I want to treat this as a graphene layer in an external electric field (similar to a plate capacitor). Is there a suited modelling software that can give me the fermi level of the graphene sheet as a function of the external electric field strength?
Thanks a bunch in advance!


+1. Welcome to our community.

SIESTA
With SIESTA and its TranSIESTA module, you can model all you are looking for.
From the SIESTA site:

SIESTA is both a method and its computer program implementation, to perform efficient electronic structure calculations and ab initio molecular dynamics simulations of molecules and solids. SIESTA's efficiency stems from the use of a basis set of strictly-localized atomic orbitals. A very important feature of the code is that its accuracy and cost can be tuned in a wide range, from quick exploratory calculations to highly accurate simulations matching the quality of other approaches, such as plane-wave methods.

About its transport capabilities:

Starting from version 3.0, SIESTA includes the TranSIESTA module, which provides the ability to model open-boundary systems where ballistic electron transport is taking place. Using TranSIESTA one can compute electronic transport properties, such as the zero-bias conductance and the I-V characteristic, of a nanoscale system in contact with two electrodes at different electrochemical potentials.

Here you have the information about how to get it, and here you have access to SIESTA documentations (manuals, tutorials, etc.).
As the Fermi level is part of the output in every SIESTA calculation, you can add the electric field and monitor it. From the SIESTA manual (v5.0, page 115), the way to add an electric field is:

%block ExternalElectricField 〈None〉
(block)
It specifies an external electric field for molecules, chains and slabs. The electric field should be
orthogonal to “bulk directions”, like those parallel to a slab (bulk electric fields, like in dielectrics
or ferroelectrics, are not allowed). If it is not, an error message is issued and the components
of the field in bulk directions are suppressed automatically. The input is a vector in Cartesian
coordinates, in the specified units.

%block ExternalElectricField
0.000 0.000 0.500 V/Ang
%endblock ExternalElectricField


Hi Camps, thanks a lot for the quick answer! I'll have a look into SIESTA.
